# Output the results of these two tables

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

**UPDATED SQL**

```
SELECT listTitle, listLength, listCmt, listDt,mBCFName, mBCLName, moAmt
FROM User U
INNER JOIN Listing L on (U.uID = L.uID)
INNER JOIN MerchantOffer MO ON (L.listID = MO.listID)
INNER JOIN Merchant M on (M.mID = MO.mId) 
GROUP BY listTitle
ORDER BY listDt DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

**Slightly updated PHP**

```
    <?php 
    $result = $sth1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    require_once('inc/php/timeAgo.php');
    echo $then;
    foreach($result as $row)
    { 
    echo "<div class='listing'>";
        print '<br>Title: ' . $row['listTitle'] . '<br>Comment: ' . $row['listCmt'] . 
        '<br><br>' . $days . ' days ' . $hours . ' hours ago' . '<br><br>' . '<br>Offer By: ' . $row['mBCFName']. ' ' . $row['mBCLName'] . '<br> for: ' . $row['moAmt'];
    echo "</div>";
    }
    unset($sth1);   
    ?>
```

Gives output like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNfU5.png

**It should really be outputting ... for example:**

```
Title: Apple iPhone 4S
Comment: need this one quick!

15254 days 15 hours ago


Offer By: Diana Matthews
for: 194.99

Offer By: John Dickinson
for: 185.99
```

**Why does it ONLY get the FIRST record and stop?**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  listTitle, listLength, listCmt, listDt
  , GROUP_CONCAT(mBFName) as BFNames
  , GROUP_CONCAT(MBCLName) as MBCLNames
  , GROUP_CONCAT(mo_Amt) as Amounts
FROM User U
INNER JOIN Listing L on (U.uID = L.uID)
INNER JOIN MerchantOffer MO ON (L.listID = MO.listID)
INNER JOIN Merchant M on (M.mID = MO.mId) 
GROUP BY listTitle
ORDER BY listDt DESC;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Note that group_concat uses ',' as a separator by default, but you can also do:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(mo_Amt, SEPARATOR '<br/>') as Amounts  
-- or even
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('<td>',moAmt,'</td>'), SEPARATOR '') as Amounts_in_a_table
```

Comment: More of an output problem. Can you see the above *new* picture i included? It doesnt show the person's offer like 199.99 for each name, see the above please!

Comment: @Jay,   I'm not here to write your code for you in copy-pasteble form, I'm just pointing out `oh that's a way of doing things kind-of-code`.

Comment: I'm really appreciate it Johan. Please?

Comment: Ah well, use `group_concat(concat(MBCLname,':',mo_Amt)) as names_and_offers` to link names and offers together. You'd use html tags for a table for that `<tr><td>name:offer</td>....</tr>`

Comment: Please see updated code for php and mysql... I'm getting CLOSER to what I want, but it seems it isnt looping through the results now. Can you please offer some guidance ? Thanks Johan!

Comment: @jay search for [php] [mysql] and see how other people loop through the results of a query. Hint: its a while loop. Keep it up you are gettong close.